# Joint uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Let (X,Y) have uniform distribution on the set  {
${(x,y)∣0 <x<2, 0 < y < 4, x < y }$}

Find a) $P(X < 1)$ and b) $P(Y < X^2)$

The answer I got for a) is $4/8 = 1/2$ since if we draw this area as a rectangle, $x < 1$ is 1/2 of the rectangle and for part b) I got 1/3 since the area under the curve $y = x^2$ is $(8/3)/8 = 1/3$.

However the answer in the book for a) is 7/12 and b) is 5/36. What am I doing wrong and how can I arrive at the correct answer?

Comment: The area is not a rectangle (it is a trapezium)

Answer (score 3):

The area of the whole trapezium is $6$, so we need to divide any areas we calculate by $6$ in order to get the probability.

We have

$$\Pr(X\leq 1)=\frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{4+3}{2}\right]=\frac{7}{12}$$

where the term in brackets is the area of the trapezium with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,4)$,$(4,4)$.

While

$$\Pr(Y\leq X^2)=\frac{1}{6}\int_1^2(x^2-x)dx=\frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^2=\frac{1}{6}\left[\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\right]=\frac{5}{36}$$

where the integral is the area below $y=x^2$ and above $y=x$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to the answer by smcc, here's an image of the set.

[image]